# Return words with three consecutive double letters (e.g. bookkeeper) in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to find all the words with three consecutive double letters, e.g., bookkeeper.

Currently its giving me any word with double letters, rather than three consecutive sets.

This is where I am at:

```
Collins <- Collins %>%
filter(nchar(test) >= 5)

dbl_letter <- function(word, position){
  substring(word, position, position) == substring(word, position+1, position+1)
  }


for(word in Collins$test){
    for(i in 1:nchar(word)){
      if(dbl_letter(word,i) == TRUE & dbl_letter(word,i+2) == TRUE  & dbl_letter(word,i+4) == TRUE){
        print(word)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: create a regular expression, and find function which matches strings against a regular expression.

Comment: in your code you need loop to nchar(word)-5, not nchar(word).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using regular expression could possibly help you out:

```r
word <- c("bookkeeper", "parrot", "oomm", "wordcloud", "oooooo", "aaaaa")
grepl("([A-Za-z])\\1([A-Za-z])\\2([A-Za-z])\\3", word)
```

`grepl` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` if there are three consectuive double letters, including six times the same letter. The vector `word` as defined above gives us

```r
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

#### Ignoring the case

The regular expression given above fails when the consectuive double letters are of different cases. So `boOkKeEper` fails the test. We can solve this by transforming the words to lower cases (or upper cases):

```r
grepl("([A-Za-z])\\1([A-Za-z])\\2([A-Za-z])\\3", tolower(word))
```

In this case the regular expression simplifies to

```r
grepl("([a-z])\\1([a-z])\\2([a-z])\\3", tolower(word))
```

Comment: Thank you that was a helpful alternative. Also @user31264's suggestion also solved it for me.